# Trying to enable conservative rasterization fails

Tags: c++, graphics, gpgpu, vulkan

I am trying to follow Sacha Willems' example on conservative rasterization.

To that effect I added tried requesting the extensions when making my device:

```cpp
const std::vector<const char*> DEVICE_EXTENSIONS = {
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_DYNAMIC_RENDERING_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_EXT_EXTENDED_DYNAMIC_STATE_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_EXT_CONSERVATIVE_RASTERIZATION_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME
};

    vk::DeviceCreateInfo create_info = {};
    create_info.queueCreateInfoCount = queue_create_infos.size();
    create_info.pQueueCreateInfos = queue_create_infos.data();
    create_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    create_info.enabledExtensionCount = DEVICE_EXTENSIONS.size();
    create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = DEVICE_EXTENSIONS.data();
    create_info.pEnabledFeatures = &device_features;
    /* ... */
```

However when I try to load some of the extension functions, it fails:

```cpp
vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR_NE = (PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR) vkGetInstanceProcAddr(
        instance, "vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR");
Assert(vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR_NE,
        "Failed to find extension function: vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR");
```

```
Failed check: vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR_NE

Failed to find extension function: vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR
```

I know that the extension is available in my card:

```
vulkaninfo | grep extensi | grep conservative
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
        VK_EXT_conservative_rasterization         : extension revision 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2` is an instance level extension (see the name chapter of the [extension spec](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2.html)), but you are enabling it at the device level. That's why loading it's function pointer via `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` fails. You need to enable that extension at instance creation time.